# Can I forecast using two year data

Tags: regression, forecasting

I have data for sales of a company over a period of two years. I want to forecast demand for the next year. What is the process for doing the same? Can I do it with two years?

Comment: Is it weekly or monthly data or just two years?

Comment: It is a monthly data

Comment: Do you mean forecast sales given some potential prices, or just forecast sales without regard for price?

Comment: Without regard for price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you read or at least browse "Forecasting: principles and practice" available at
 https://www.otexts.org/fpp/

The author gives step by step instructions on how to approach your problem.

Comment: Be sure to like my answer :)